# Writing values to excel in python using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop

I'm new to python and would like to pass the ZipCode in excel file to 'uszipcode' package and write the state for that particular zipcode to 'OriginalZipcode' column in the excel sheet. The reason for doing this is, I want to compare the existing states with the original states. I don't understand if the for loop is wrong in the code or something else is. Currently, I cannot write the states to OriginalZipcode column in excel. The code I've written is:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import uszipcode as US
from uszipcode import ZipcodeSearchEngine
search = ZipcodeSearchEngine()
df = pd.read_excel("H:\excel\checking for zip and states\checkZipStates.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
#print(df.values)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    zipcode = search.by_zipcode(row['ZipCode']) #for searching zipcode
    b = zipcode.State
    df.at['row','OriginalState'] = b
    df.to_excel("H:\\excel\\checking for zip and states\\new.xlsx", sheet_name = "compare", index = False)
```

The excel sheet is in this format:

```
| ZipCode   |CurrentState     | OriginalState |
|-----------|-----------------|---------------|
| 59714     | Montana         |               |
| 29620     | South Carolina  |               |
| 54405     | Wisconsin       |               |
|    .      | .               |               |
|    .      | .               |               |
```

Comment: you're saving your excel file with each iteration of the loop. you probably want to save outside of your loop. also, for all intents and purposes, your zip code question has nothing to do with your problem. so I would simplify to just include, e.g., looking up a key in a dictionary or something like that.

Comment: @PaulH don't I have to write the respective states to the excel file each iteration since I'm reading the zipcodes in a loop?

Comment: I'm able to print the states in the output console by reading zipcode from the excel. That means for-loop is working fine. But, I'm not sure if df.at['row', 'OriginalState'] = b is the right way to write into a cell in the excel. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `print(df)` outside of your loop will tell you if the values have been properly assigned

Comment: Simply do not quote *row* in `df.at`: `df.at[row,'OriginalState'] = b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the OriginalState column without iterating the df:

Define a function that returns the value you want for any given zip code:

```
def get_original_state(state):
    zipcode = search.by_zipcode(state) #for searching zipcode
    return zipcode.State
```

Then:

```
df['OriginalState'] = df.apply( lambda row: get_original_state(row['ZipCode']), axis=1)
```

Finally, export only once the df to excel.

This should do the trick.

Comment: That works, thank you! Now, I'll have to dig more regarding the usage of df.apply()